# how to convert date using awk linux

Tags: date, awk, converters

I have txt file (**test.txt**) contains the following data:

```
00:06:55.351;C39EE9AF;2015-01-05 09:52:20;0;5;295;test;
00:06:51.368;C39EE78B;2015-01-05 09:52:17;0;5;295;test2;
```

I need to view date as below using awk, like this:

```
2015-01-05 test
2015-01-05 test2
```

I have tried the following:

```
cat test.txt | awk -v FS=";" '{print $3,$7}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the field separate to a semicolon *or* a space:

```
awk -F'[; ]' '{ print $3, $NF }' test.txt
```

I have used the `-F` switch, which is the standard way to set the input field separator `FS`. I have also used `$NF` to print the last field. Also note that I am passing the file directly to awk, which avoids a useless use of cat.

If there may be spaces within the other fields, then you could use `split` instead like this:

```
awk -F; '{ split($3,a," "); print a[1], $NF }' file
```

This splits the third field on a space and uses the first part.

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the tick next to it. Thanks.

Comment: if the last field ="adv test" i got
2015-01-06 test
2015-01-06 adv

Comment: I've made a guess about what you problem might be and edited my answer.